# Develop InApp Purchase for Client

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

one of my clients requested an InApp Purchase for their app. As I have never done this, I am running into some issues. Here's one of them:

I linked StoreKit.framekwork, and then to enable InApp Purchase, I open the "Capabilities" Tab on the app's target and go to InApp Purchase. Xcode has marked the linking step as completed, but wants me to sign in to "Add the In-App Purchase entitlement" to your App ID".

The customer has their own iTunes Connect account where they wish to upload the app themselves and have already created the necessary iTunes Connect entries.

What do I do? Is there an alternative way to asking them to provide their iTunes Connect credentials?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could ask them to add you to their team so you can use their certs, or even generate them yourself.

Comment: you will be testing products created under his/her account, so best is to ask credentials and create product in it yourself. they can give you developer role inside the dev center as well as iTunes connect

Comment: If I ask them to add me, can one account be in several teams?

Comment: yes youcan be on several account. Note that they need to add you to Apple Dev for the certificates & mobileprovision and to iTunes Connect for you to create Products (and IAP test accounts)